# How to fix SDTray.exe error?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium and on start up of Windows I am getting the following error:

> **SDTray.exe - System Error**
>
> The program can't start because **vclie150.bpl** is missing from your
>   computer. Try re-installing the program to fix this problem.

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDTray.exe` is a background tray app installed by [Safer Networking's SpyBot](http://www.safer-networking.org/). `vclie150.bpl` is also a file which belongs to this program, and normally should be located inside its app folder in `Program Files`.

Reinstalling the application (SpyBot) should fix the problem.

Also, sometimes different anti-virus and anti-malware programs remove each other's components because they find virus signatures inside. If you have an anti-virus program installed, you can also check its "vault" or a similarly-named thrash can to see if your file has ended up there.